# How is the order of the for each loop exactly specified in VBA when looping through named ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I often use named ranges in order to specify what ranges my VBA loops should loop through. I then use code like this to loop through the range and conduct operations on it.

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In SheetName.Range("Name1")
   call DoStuff(cell)
Next cell
```

I noticed that the order in which the cells get activated depends on the order in which you select the range before you name it. But even then the order sometimes isn't as expected (I would expect it to be top to bottom, left to right). I know that this could easily be solved with a regular loop, but that's not the question.

The question is:

**How does the order get determined and how can I predict the order in a for each loop in a named range?**

Comment: Have two loops for row and column to ensure a specific order.

Comment: Doubling up on SJRs comment; view [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837959/loop-through-rows-and-columns-excel-macro-vba?rq=1) to see how you can accomplish your request.