# Excel VBA to loop through cell column and paste in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

**What I've done so far :-**
1. VBA script to open a template word document. copy the value from column(A1) and paste it in a word document by using the find function.
2. I have done this with two columns for two different locations in a word document.
3. Then, I have saved the document using the value from column(A1).

**What I wish to do:-**
1. Right now, this runs only for one word document.
2. I wish to run a loop such that I can copy each row into a word document, save it and move onto the next row and save the template word document with a unique name(i.e, from column A)
3. based on the code below, I'm guessing I need two loops, I just can't figure it out and would love some help.

Code I've written so far:-
1. some of them return the function call and didn't think it would be useful, thus I didn't paste it.

```
Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWd.Visible = True
Set docWD = appWd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Draft.docx")

'Select Sheet where copying from in excel
Set sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wdFind = appWd.Selection.Find
ClipT = "  "
ClipEmpty.SetText ClipT

sheet1.Range("A1").Copy
wdFind.Text = "DateHere"
Call FormatPaste

sheet1.Range("B1").Copy
wdFind.Text = "EntryHere"
Call FormatPaste

saveCell1 = sheet1.Range("B1").Text
dir2 = "C:\Users\" & saveCell1
docWD.SaveAs (dir2 & ".docx")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through rows and columns Excel Macro VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837959/loop-through-rows-and-columns-excel-macro-vba)

Comment: you ask two different questions at once, which isn't what you should do here.  please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).