# Error on looping through rows and columns in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi Excel stackoverflow,

I have a background in JavaScript/jQuery, as well as some PHP/SQL, but the syntax for VBA is still new and confusing to me.

As the title says, I'm wanting to loop through rows and columns in VBA. I have a table of recipes for ceramic glazes stored like so:

[image: [image of db]]

Not all recipes have the same amount of ingredients. Some have a lot, some have only a few. I want to generate a list of recipes with the title of the recipe followed by the ingredients and the amount of each ingredient, like so:

[image: [image with sample recipes]]

I've found a solution that generates what I want, but I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error and don't understand why or how to resolve it. I've modified a code snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837959/loop-through-rows-and-columns-excel-macro-vba):

```
Sub ExtractRecipes()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Worksheets("cone6")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Worksheets("output")
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 1
    On Error Resume Next

    With wsDest
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            .Cells(RowCounter, 1) = wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable").ListColumns("recipe").DataBodyRange.Cells(i)
            For j = 1 To LastCol
                If wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                    .Cells(RowCounter + 1, 1) = wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable").ListColumns("material_" & j).DataBodyRange.Cells(i)
                    .Cells(RowCounter + 1, 2) = wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable").ListColumns("material_amount_" & j).DataBodyRange.Cells(i)
                    .Cells(RowCounter + 1, 3) = Err.Description
                    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

And here's the output I'm currently getting:

[image: [output]]

Can anyone explain to the newbie what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

note: for any ceramics people who may stumble on this, these recipes aren't real ;)

Comment: Can you remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see what line is failing. At a guess it's the `j` variable goes to 8 but your labeling scheme goes to 4, so there is no material_7 for instance.

Comment: Besides, the error is not cleared, so once it appears, it stays until the end.

Comment: @Warcupine sure, the line that's failing is at `.Cells(RowCounter + 1, 1) = wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable").ListColumns("material_" & j).DataBodyRange.Cells(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
Sub ExtractRecipes()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, col As Long
    Dim RowCounter As Long, rw As Range, rec, mat, amt
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("cone6")
    Set lo = wsSrc.ListObjects("testTable")
    
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("output")
    RowCounter = 1
    
    For Each rw In lo.DataBodyRange.Rows   'loop rows in listobject
        rec = rw.Cells(1).Value            'recipe
        If Len(rec) > 0 Then               'have entry?
            wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value = rec
            For col = 2 To lo.ListColumns.Count Step 2
                mat = rw.Cells(col).Value
                amt = rw.Cells(col + 1).Value
                If Len(mat) > 0 Then '+ test amount?
                    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(mat, amt)
                End If
            Next col
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1 'add empty row between
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much :) I'm guessing what's happening here is there's a step to count how many columns have a value?

Comment: Yes - `If Len(mat) > 0` checks to see if there's any material entered in that column.